# Maximum number of tasks in a workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow, tasks, boundaries

We work with SharePoint 2013.

Our workflows used to have 10-13 individual tasks for every workflow. Since upgrading to 2013 the admins (or so-called admins) are telling us that the number of tasks are now limited and they have consolidated the tasks which really seems wrong. It literally has screwed up the workflow from flowing properly. Is this a real limitation or a programming limitation of the "admins"?

Comment: Typical case of Dilbert style admins. You can add any number of Tasks to a List and they claim a Workflow can not?

Comment: yes, I was told its limited as to the number of tasks. again we had 10-13 now we have 5. I write software for CAD packages and other graphics progs and generate graphics on several packages that are triggered by these workflows. I found it very hard to believe that it was true but they insisted .... they are not formally trained in software development whatsoever and are a tad out of their league. I was even told that the due dates could not be changed to EXCLUDE the weekends... SMH... that I knew was not correct and quickly found several tech pages referring to it...

Comment: SharePoint is a big beast with so many capabilities not one man can master them all. Forget about fighting with Dilbert over tech stuff. Do the math (money the company is loosing) and convince a manager to hire a decent consultant. Dilbert looses all power when you totally ignore his existence.,

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the info. just want to make sure I have good info before I do that. its really a huge mess outside of the 2 items i'm focused on. folder organization, uploading process and this one is a gem, if you checkout a task to work on it anyone can check you back in and not notify you. this person doesn't even understand permissions....its actually laughable... but management currently doesn't know any better and likes the admin's personally... smh...

Comment: Sound like the (typical) Everyone-has-Full-Control implementation. But then you should just about be able to do anything you want as wel...See http://365csi.nl/toolkit/permissionsplanner.html?l=en